# Pointing Contiki to a Local MQTT Broker

Tags: mqtt, contiki

I have the Contiki web demo running on a CC2650 and I'm trying to troubleshooting MQTT and want to make sure I'm properly pointing the node to a local MQTT broker (Mosquitto). Is there anything else I need to do but change the broker IP on the node to the bbbb:: IPv6 address of the broker? I've tested publishing and subscribing between Linux machines using the bbbb:: IPv6 address and it is working. Is there anything I need to do with the Org Id or auth token? I've done an exhaustive search but can't seem to find any specific documentation. Here is the link to the TI tutorial for reference http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Cc26xx_sw_examples Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am now able to answer my question on this and yes you can just point a node a local MQTT broker by pointing to the IPv6 address of the Mosquitto broker. I'm troubleshooting some 6LowPAN packet loss issues which was making the reception of published messages take a long time. Subscribing to the broker for all topics with mosquitto_sub -h localhost -v -t “#” and doing a tcpdump on port 1883 (tcpdump -i eth0 -v -X port 1883) were both helpful in seeing that there was activity.